# Python 3.6 need help using randint

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numbers, operators

```
from random import randint

Secret = randint(1, 100)

Chances = 5

BotGuess = randint(1, 100)

while(BotGuess != Secret and Chances != 0):
    BotGuess = randint(1, 100)
    print("Bot: I guess " + str(BotGuess) + "!")
    Chances -= 1

    if (BotGuess > Secret):
        print("You: Nope! Try guessing lower")

    elif (BotGuess < Secret):
        print("You: Nope! Try guessing higher")

    elif (BotGuess == Secret and Chances > 0):
        print("You: Wow! You win.")

    elif (Chances == 0):
        print("You: You're out of chances! You lose")


    else:
        print("Shouldn't be possible")
```

How would I implement when I tell the bot to guess higher, his range goes from (1, 100) to between his guess + 1 and 100? And vise versa for when I tell him to guess lower. Semi new to python.

Also any tips on the look and flow of my code are much appreciated!

Comment: First, a few tips regarding your programming "style". In Python, if you want to follow conventions, you should use `_` to separate words in a variable name and not "camel case". Also, you don't need parenthesis in the `if` and `while` statements. Another piece of advice that I recommend you to follow is to start using functions as a way of modularizing your code.

Comment: @nbro I disagree with your statement on "camelCase" If you pop open the source code of python itself, you'll find both are used. As long as a convention is agreed upon with whomever you're collaborating with, either is fine. I personally in fact prefer camelCase because underscores typically indicate internal functions such as `__call__` and such

Comment: @Aaron camelCase is used in some places inside the source code of Python because at the time those modules were written probably these conventions still didn't exist (or were different). Check here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. But I agree with you, it's more important to be consistent with your own style or the style accorded by your company or team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving fixed parameters to `randint`, you can use variables which you change in your conditionals:

```
from random import randint

Secret = randint(1, 100)

Chances = 5

min_guess = 1
max_guess= 100

BotGuess = randint(1, 100)

while(BotGuess != Secret and Chances != 0):
    BotGuess = randint(min_guess, max_guess)
    print("Bot: I guess " + str(BotGuess) + "!")
    Chances -= 1

    if (BotGuess > Secret):
        print("You: Nope! Try guessing lower")
        max_guess = BotGuess - 1

    elif (BotGuess < Secret):
        print("You: Nope! Try guessing higher")
        min_guess = BotGuess + 1

    elif (BotGuess == Secret and Chances > 0):
        print("You: Wow! You win.")

    elif (Chances == 0):
        print("You: You're out of chances! You lose")


    else:
        print("Shouldn't be possible")
```

A test run gave me this output:

```
Bot: I guess 68!
You: Nope! Try guessing higher
Bot: I guess 74!
You: Nope! Try guessing higher
Bot: I guess 90!
You: Nope! Try guessing higher
Bot: I guess 93!
You: Nope! Try guessing lower
Bot: I guess 92!
You: You're out of chances! You lose
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the range of the guess in variables, i.e. `minGuess` and `maxGuess`. You can set them to `1` and `100` respectively at the beginning. Now when you tell the bot to guess higher, just set the `minGuess` variable to `BotGuesss + 1`. Of course everytime you have `BotGuess = randint(1, 100)` in your code, you replace that with `BotGuess = randint(minGuess, maxGuess)`.

Also a tip on your code in general: Variables should usually begin with a lowercase letter. Your variables start with an uppercase letter, which usually indicates a Class. This is practical so you can understand code of others easier. [Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) is a complete style guide.

Answer (score 1):

[nbro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924118/nbro) recommended in a comment that you improve the style of your writing. He was saying that your code should be formatted more like this instead:

```
import random


def main():
    secret = random.randint(1, 100)
    chances = 5
    bot_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
    while bot_guess != secret and chances > 0:
        bot_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f'Bot: I guess {bot_guess}!')
        chances -= 1
        if bot_guess > secret:
            print('You: Nope! Try guessing lower.')
        elif bot_guess < secret:
            print('You: Nope! Try guessing higher.')
        elif bot_guess == secret and chances > 0:
            print('You: Won! You win.')
        elif chances == 0:
            print('You: You are out of chances! You lose.')
        else:
            raise ValueError('should not be possible')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want a program that is somewhat closer to what you are asking for, the following code may help you better in changing your own to make a smarter robot:

```
import math
import random
import time


LOW_VALUE = 1
HIGH_VALUE = 100
CHANCES = math.ceil(math.log(HIGH_VALUE - LOW_VALUE, 2))


def main():
    secret = random.randint(LOW_VALUE, HIGH_VALUE)
    robot = random.Random(math.pi * time.time())
    lo, hi = LOW_VALUE, HIGH_VALUE
    for _ in range(CHANCES):
        guess = robot.randint(lo, hi)
        print(f'Bot: I guess {guess}!')
        if guess < secret:
            print('You: Nope! Try guessing higher.')
            lo = guess + 1
        elif guess > secret:
            print('You: Nope! Try guessing lower.')
            hi = guess - 1
        else:
            print('You: Won! You win.')
            break
    else:
        print('You: You are out of chances! You lose.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```